# SDK Version Issue. This app update was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. As of June 30, 2020, updates to apps for iPhone must be built with the iOS 13 SDK

Tags: ios, angularjs, phonegap

"SDK Version Issue. This app update was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. As of June 30, 2020, updates to apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later."Type a message.

this is the issue we are facing while creating build. currently, we are using PhoneGap with angular js.

I have shared my config.xml please help me resolve this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 -<widget xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" version="0.0.1" 
 id="***************">

 <preference value="portrait" name="orientation"/>

 <preference value="none" name="permissions"/>

 <preference value="true" name="DisallowOverscroll"/>

 <preference value="false" name="UIWebViewBounce"/>

 <name>Accomplishment Calender</name>

 <access launch-external="yes" origin="*"/>

 <access launch-external="yes" origin="geo:*"/>

 <description>Accomplishment Calender</description>

 <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">Accomplishment Calender</author>


 -<feature name="Device">

 <param value="CDVDevice" name="ios-package"/>

 </feature>


 -<feature name="File">

 <param value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" name="android-package"/>

 </feature>


 -<feature name="FileTransfer">

  <param value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" name="android-package"/>

  </feature>


  -<feature name="InAppBrowser">

  <param value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" name="android-package"/>

  </feature>


  -<feature name="File">

   <param value="CDVFile" name="ios-package"/>

  </feature>


   -<feature name="FileTransfer">

     <param value="CDVFileTransfer" name="ios-package"/>

   </feature>


  -<feature name="Capture">

   <param value="org.apache.cordova.Capture" name="android-package"/>

   </feature>


    -<feature name="Camera">

    <param value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" name="android-package"/>

   </feature>


   -<feature name="Notification">

     <param value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" name="android-package"/>

   </feature>


   -<feature name="Vibration">

    <param value="org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration" name="android-package"/>

   </feature>


  -<feature name="Geolocation">

  <param value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" name="android-package" source="npm"/>

  </feature>

  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>

  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>

  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>

   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.4.1"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="1.2.0"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>

   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="4.3.1"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.6.1"/>

   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-webintent"/>

   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation" source="npm"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm"/>

  <!-- <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" /> -->


  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="3.0.0"/>

   <!-- <gap:plugin name="customer-header-inappbrowser" source="npm" /> -->


  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm"/>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release" source="npm"/>

   <!-- <gap:plugin name="cordova-sms-plugin" source="npm" /> -->


   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-share" source="npm"/>

    <preference value="14" name="android-minSdkVersion"/>

   <preference value="19+" name="xwalkVersion"/>

    <preference value="gradle" name="android-build-tool"/>

   <!-- FCM Notificaitons -->



   -<platform name="android">

   <resource-file target="google-services.json" src="google-services.json"/>

    <resource-file target="res/drawable/myImage.png" src="myImage.png"/>

    <resource-file target="res/raw/msSound.mp3" src="msSound.mp3"/>

   </platform>


   -<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="1.9.0">

   <variable value="1:39390195386:android:bc0a0e46496783969b1c83" name="SENDER_ID"/>

   </plugin>

   <icon src="icon.png"/>

   <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>

   <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>

   <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>

   <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>

   <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>

   <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>

   <splash src="new_splash.jpg"/>


  -<platform name="android">

   <allow-intent href="market:*"/>

  <preference value="14" name="android-minSdkVersion"/>

  <preference value="22" name="android-targetSdkVersion"/>

  <preference value="splash" name="SplashScreen"/>

  <preference value="3000" name="SplashScreenDelay"/>

   <preference value="false" name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner"/>

  <preference value="false" name="FadeSplashScreen"/>

  <preference value="true" name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio"/>

  <preference value="false" name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime"/>

  <preference value="false" name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime"/>

  <splash src="res/drawable-land-hdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="land-hdpi"/>

  <splash src="res/drawable-land-ldpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="land-ldpi"/>

  <splash src="res/drawable-land-mdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="land-mdpi"/>

  <splash src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="land-xhdpi"/>

  <splash src="res/drawable-land-xxhdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="land-xxhdpi"/>

   <splash src="res/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="land-xxxhdpi"/>

  <splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="port-hdpi"/>

 <splash src="res/drawable-port-ldpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="port-ldpi"/>

 <splash src="res/drawable-port-mdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="port-mdpi"/>

 <splash src="res/drawable-port-xhdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>

 <splash src="res/drawable-port-xxhdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="port-xxhdpi"/>

 <splash src="res/drawable-port-xxxhdpi/new_splash.jpg" qualifier="port-xxxhdpi"/>

 </platform>

 </widget>
```

Comment: You need to use Xcode 11 toolchain

Comment: we do not use xcode to make build, we use build.phonegap.com to make build

Comment: Google turns up [this thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/phonegap/ios-13-sdk-for-phonegap-build/td-p/10816613?page=1). I didn't read it in depth, there are some suggestions to convert to native tools,  but it looks like the end of the road for phonegap